# Can a WKWebView hosting an "HTTPS" url listen to a "LocalHost WebServer" via a "WebSocket Connection" in an iOS Application?

Tags: webserver, webkit, mobile-webkit

**Problem Description:** In the current scenario, I am dealing with a website platform that lacks traditional APIs for service access. To circumvent this limitation, the mobile application necessitates hosting a "web server" locally on "ws://127.0.0.1:****". The idea is that the website, loaded in a WKWebView, should establish a WebSocket connection with the locally hosted server. The responsibility for creating this WebSocket lies with the loaded website. I am utilizing "Telegraph" to set up the local server within the iOS application. To verify the functionality of the local Webserver, I attempted to establish a WebSocket connection to it outside of the WKWebView, and the connection was successfully established.

**Question:** Despite the success of the direct WebSocket connection outside of WKWebView, I am encountering difficulties when attempting to establish the same connection within the WKWebView. Is this approach even feasible? If it is, could you kindly point out any potential oversights or provide guidance on what might be missing in my implementation? Your assistance in resolving this matter is greatly appreciated.

To verify the functionality of the local Webserver, I attempted to establish a WebSocket connection to it outside of the WKWebView, and the connection was successfully established.